# springboot api service: "status": 404, "error": "Not Found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I am having a very weird error with Spring, and apparently my code does not create the right endpoints for the API.
When I open the Web Browser and try to access the endpoint at http://localhost:8081/contacts/retrieveAll I always get a 404 as answer.
And this is what the console says:

```
2023-08-03T15:06:10.176+02:00  INFO 18340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-08-03T15:06:10.188+02:00 DEBUG 18340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/contacts/", parameters={}
2023-08-03T15:06:10.194+02:00  WARN 18340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /contacts/
2023-08-03T15:06:10.195+02:00 DEBUG 18340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

In the code below you can see that that:

- port is surely 8081 (Tomcat confirms it in the console too)
- the Controller class defines the API as I use it: /contacts + /retrieveAll (I literally copied a pre-existent code and just changed names and some logic in the functions for this class)

So I leave you my code here, hoping that somebody is able to spot the problem.
I have been testing all morning and I start thinking it is something very hard to spot, or something very stupid and, at the moment, invisible to my eyes.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "name_person")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "surname_person")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModified;
    
    //No args - JPA's reflection 
    public Person() {
    }
    
    public Person(String phoneNumber, String name, String surname) {
    ...
    }
    
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        lastModified = new Date();
    }

    // getters and setters...
}
```

The contacts class:

```
public class AddressBook {

    private List<Person> persons;

    public AddressBook() {
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        persons.add(person);
    }

    public void removePerson(Person person) {
        persons.remove(person);
    }
}
```

The JpaRepository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {
   @Override
   Person save(Person person);
   @Override
   @Cacheable("persons")
   List<Person> findAll();
   void deleteByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
   List<Person> searchBySurname(String surname);
   List<Person> searchByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
}
```

AddressBookService class:

```
@Service
public class AddressBookService {
    private final AddressBook addressBook;

    public AddressBookService() {
        this.addressBook = new AddressBook();
    }

    public List<Person> retrieveAll() {
        return addressBook.getPersons();
    }

}
```

AddressBookController class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public class AddressBookController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
  
    @GetMapping("/retrieveAll")
    public ResponseEntity<?> retrieveContacts() {
        List<Person> contacts = personRepository.findAll();

        if (contacts.isEmpty()) 
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Nobody found in the address book.");
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(contacts);
    }
```

The SpringApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AddressBookSampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AddressBookSampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.unicredit</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <!-- Replace version with the appropriate version for your MySQL server -->
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql80
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

server.port=8081
debug=true
```

Comment: 1. remove the `org.hibernate.javax.persistence` dependency, if you get compilation errors fix them (use `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence`. 2. Remove all the annotations you have on your `@SpringBootApplication` class but the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. Place the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the `it.example` package.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks! Already done both, the problem does not change at all. 
I am now updating the question with new dependencies and code

Comment: No you haven't done both, you removed all your dependencies, I doubt it will even start in the current situation. Remove the `javax.persistence-api` add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Copied wrong project pom, now you can see I simplified everything and put only one simple GET endpoint. Still nothing and still saem exact error of unexisting api.

Console now says:
`Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.`

Comment: No you didn't... As statedf remove `jakarta.persistence-api` you don't need a `persistence-api` version as that is already included in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. If that line is shown your application wouldn't even start as the controller would blow up as it needs the repository. If your application starts tha tmeans your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class isn't in a top-level package covering all other packages.

Comment: @M.Deinum they are not integrated, there is the need to install javax.persistence or jakarta.persistence to use those annotations.

Comment: They are those dependecies come from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. But as stated your app wouldn't even start right now, if it does the structure isn't as I said it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your application is hosted on a context path. For me it is hosted at **/pimservice** . This path needs to be prepended before any URI you host.

```
2023-08-03T19:26:14.587+05:30  INFO 13644 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8087 (http) with context path '/pimservice'
```

From your question logs says

```
2023-08-03T15:06:10.194+02:00  WARN 18340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /contacts/
```

The path is /contacts/ and not /contacts/retriveAll . It looks like you are making some mistake on client side.

Comment: Nope, simple Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http)